# ActionScript3.0 MouseEvent and TextChange

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'd like to make an external ActionScript 3 that when `MOUSE_UP` the text will change and when `MOUSE_DOWN` no text will be displayed.

This is the code that I made:

```
this.parent.getChildByName("planet_name").text = "EARTH";
```

I just made this code up to show point. =P

Comment: this is what I want @bitmapdata.com

Comment: Just a little wait.  i answer a brief description and I'll post the link.

Comment: no problem. I'm taking note of your explanations here.. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check first. this.parent.getChildByName("plant_name") is Whether DynamicText or not

If not, you must change instance of DynamicText.

what is "plant_name" instance ? if is instance of MovieClip, you change DynamicText.

**`How to changed?`**

1. MovieClip click
2. ctrl+b
3. property change to DynamicText

I will omit a more detailed description. the source code, refer to the following link.
As you will see the source code, There are a DragAndDrop Class . 
this Class The role of this class of objects on the stage all the initialization and is responsible for managing.

[DragAndDrop_Modification](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-c439d56c.html)

Oh, and by the Class name must be start a capital letter. This is customary promise among the developers.

**goodLuck**

Comment: sorry.. I slept last night.. I tried it but it doesn't work. and the file you sent didn't work too..

Comment: Oh, sorry My Flash Version CS6.0 how you? CS5.5? or CS5.0? 
i've check not working. I'll give correct and again.

Comment: I edited my Answers recheck link DragAndDrop_Modification please. When you unzip. 3 kinds of Fla file you can view. For your preferred version open! at least CS5.0

Comment: Oops, I forgot one thing. open DragAndDrops.as add a follow code at line 45. _txtField.text = "";

Comment: NICE! haha.. This is it! thank you so much.. it's done now.. =)

Answer (score 0):

So by external do you mean a parent of the displayobject(movieclip, sprite, etc.) from where the code is called?

Assuming MOUSE_UP and MOUSE_DOWN is on the displayObject where you write the code you could do something like this:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, handleMouseUp);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, handleMouseDown);

function handleMouseDown(event : MouseEvent) : void {
   this.parent.textFieldName.visible = false;
}

function handleMouseUp(event : MouseEvent) : void {
   this.parent.textFieldName.visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you add this in your document class (main class):

```
public static var me:DocumentClassName;
```

and this in your document class constructor:

```
me = this;
```

In the external AS3 file just add 2 eventListeners:

```
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseup);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mousedown);

function mouseup(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
   DocumentClassName.me.textFieldName.text = "EARTH";
}

function mousedown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
   DocumentClassName.me.textFieldName.text = " ";
}
```

Change DocumentClassName with you document class name. It's usually Main. Also change textFieldName with the instance name of the object.